# What do you call a permutation that is no where identity?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

I want to write a formula for $n!$.

$n!$ is the number of permutation functions on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Let's define a "true k-permutation" on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ as a permutation that is identity on exactly $n-k$ elements, i.e., if $\phi$ is a $k$-permutation then $\phi(i) = i$ only on $n-k$ elements.

This seems like an elementary object yet I don't know what you call such perms (That is my question).

Notice that the relation $\phi$ *is a true $k$-permutation* partitions the group of permutations on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

So there is a formula for $n!$ involving counting of true $k$-perms.  The one I have involves sum partitions of $k$ and disjoint compositions of cycles.  But there's probably other ways to count them.

But this has to have been done already, so I would appreciate it if someone could post a link.

Comment: It does not hurt if you had to type in `permutation` instead of `perm`. Reading that several times makes me feel weird!

Comment: You should check the following link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: And perhaps more relevantly this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers, which is linked to from the one Dennis mentioned.

Comment: Your first sentence is puzzling. Surely you know a formula for $n!$ that doesn't require counting the permutations with $n-k$ fixed points (which is the usual way to designate your "true $k$ permutations") separately?

Comment: Thanks @Arturo Magidin.  I will typeset fully in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A permutation which leaves no element fixed (what you call a "true $n$-permutation") is called a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). I know of no common term for "true $k$-permutations" in general.

Comment: Well, probably they are usually just called permutations with support size $k$.  (The support of a permutation $\sigma$ is the set of points moved by $\sigma$.)